# Using `Focusout` on Table td on `contenteditable = "true"`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where i am trying to do convert the field to editable when clicked with mouse,
But again when focus is out i want that field to convert back to its own position which is normal td without `contenteditable` attribute.

adding attribute is going fine, but its the focusout() which is giving problem, its not working for certain column of table.

## [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/J4V5C/15/)

the focusout only works if i comeback and click on the column and goback to some other td.. i want the focusout to work instantly after i move to some other td?

Am i missing something or i would have to follow some other process to have editable columns in my table when pressed on them and when focusout they go back to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus will fail for tables in older browsers, instead remove the attribute and class from all $cells on body or cell click then enable it for the active cell.

```
        //Now Need to Get Available Months on Based of Year
    var $cell = $('tr.tableRow td.inner'),
        $body = $('body');
    $body.on('click',function(e){
        if($cell.children(e.target).length == 0 && $cell.index(e.target) == -1){
            $cell.attr('contentEditable','false')
                .removeClass('inputCopyCat');
        }
    });
    $cell.on('click',function(){
        $cell.attr('contentEditable','false')
             .removeClass('inputCopyCat');            
        $(this).attr('contentEditable','true');
        $(this).addClass('inputCopyCat');
    });
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/yhjw23of/**

Comment: Actually i was missing .focus(), did some update in my fucntion and its working great.
http://jsfiddle.net/yhjw23of/1/
your method did worked too.. but problem it had that is was not focusing in when pressed on so i had to click two times to get the focus. but many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On focus out you need to make the ***contentEditable*** attribute to ***false*** and also remove the ***inputCopyCat*** class.

```
$('tr.tableRow td.inner').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(this).attr('contentEditable','true');
        $(this).addClass('inputCopyCat');
        $(this).focusout(function(e){
            // here's what you need to update in your code
            $(this).attr('contentEditable','false');
            $(this).removeClass('inputCopyCat');
        });
        console.log($(this));
    });
    $('tr.tableRow td.inner').focusout(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('Hello');
    });
```

and as you want to switch back to default view immediately after you move to other td, then instead of using [***focusout***](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) use [***mouseleave***](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).

```
$('tr.tableRow td.inner').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(this).attr('contentEditable','true');
        $(this).addClass('inputCopyCat');
        // this mouseleave event will be fired when you leave the selected/focused td 
        $(this).mouseleave(function(e){
            $(this).attr('contentEditable','false');
            $(this).removeClass('inputCopyCat');
        });
        console.log($(this));
    });
    $('tr.tableRow td.inner').focusout(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('Hello');
    });
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/h4nugLxv/)

Comment: Thankyou. problem solved already, your solution is also ok but it would not be good practice using mouse out as user can get irritated if mouse went out and td goes back to normal non-editable position.

Comment: @SizzlingCode, you mentioned, "i want the focusout to work instantly after i move to some other td". Move to some other td means mouseleave.

Comment: And I really appreciate an explanation for the downvote who voted.

Comment: xD, how would i know.. you need to ask the stackoverflow team. :)